# Hide "index.php" from URL and get parameters

Tags: php, html, apache, .htaccess

Yes, this is another .httaccess question...

I swear to god I tried everything I could to make this work, but I can't understand clearly how to write the rules.

What i want is: to type in my browser "mydomain.com/x/10" and it should be interpreted as "mydonain.com/index.php?x=10" so i can get the x value and use it.

I wanna do this so it's easier to link stuff to people.

How do i do this? Also, if someone could provide me a link to a place where I can actually learn how to construct the regular expressions that htaccess use, that would be awesome.

Comment: Come on, every second result in Google gives a complete copypastable example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, yet another .htaccess answer ;)

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews

RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

# Internally forward /x/10 to /index.php?x=10
RewriteRule ^x/(.*)/?$ index.php?x=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

This will redirect:

```
http://yourdomain.com/x/10
```

Internally to:

```
http://yourdomain.com/index.php?x=10
```

So on the user does not see that on the browser.

---

[**As for the link to learn about it, I found this a very good one specially because of the images describing what is going on.**](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/rewrite/intro.html)

Comment: gotta love ranking in the upvote credits for these questions that are asked over and over.. lol

Comment: @gorelative if you feel that way you should propose it as a question to the moderator candidates and see if you can change something, as I have tried in the past and no, SO doesn't want to change or so it seems.

Comment: if i'm testing this on localhost, in a /project folder inside my htdocs, should I change the RewriteBase / to /project?

Comment: @user3307966 yes. if project is the root folder for your test scenario. And in that case you might want to remove the `/` from index.php