# mod rewrite mysql php

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a website with rental properties and want to change the url with mod_rewrite .htaccess and mysql.

```
http://www.example/property.php?id=2112
```

into

```
http:/www.example/house/spain/costa-del-sol/malaga/2112
```

each property is in a table called HOUSE I need to get the url stored in the table by referencing the id number.

> HOUSE
>  id - 2112
>  ......
>  ......
>  ......
>  url -
>   http://www.example/house/spain/costa-del-sol/malaga/2112

I am a newbie to this mod rewrite stuff, I figured I need somesort of .htaccess file that redirects to a php file to do the lookup. Is there a way in .htaccess to only do this lookup if the filename is property.php?id= - otherwise go to my 404.php

Regards
        Martyn

Comment: Same question as : [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766177/hide-index-php-from-url-and-get-parameters][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21766177/hide-index-php-from-url-and-get-parameters

Comment: And due to the second reason, it is unlikely any answer will be helpful, or that this question will be helpful to other people.

Comment: Thanks JooO for the pointer to that previous question, it gives me great info to help try and understand this. At times research is difficult if you cannot always explain what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: @kingkero - Perhaps you should read this: http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/215546/135615

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add a URL Rewrite rule:

```
RewriteRule    ^house/spain/([0-9]+)/?$    property.php?id=$1    [NC,L]
```

To get:

```
http://www.example/house/spain/2112
```

If you want add some informations, such as **costa-del-sol** and **malaga**, you need this:

```
RewriteRule    ^house/spain/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+)/([0-9]+)/?$    property.php?location=$1&city=$2&id=$3    [NC,L]
```

**location** and **city** fields are for example.

**[NC,L]** - "Flags", that tell Apache how to apply the rule. In this case, we're using two flags. "NC", tells Apache that this rule should be case-insensitive, and "L" tells Apache not to process any more rules if this one is used.

Comment: Many thanks again to all - this has now given me a good pointer on constructing the very confussing Rewrite rule. Again thanks to all